# Android "squishing" game graphics into upper left corner of large screen

Tags: android

I'm doing something like the following:

`Bitmap mBitmap;`

```
mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myimage);
```

In onDraw I'm doing this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,0,0,null);
```

My Manifest looks like this:

`<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="false" />`

On Larger screens, my images shrink down to about a quarter the size of the large screen and sit in the upper left hand corner.

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get my images and screen coordinates to automatically adjust to the larger screens.

The thing is, the code above works great on most devices, like Droids and normal screens.  It's just tablets or slightly larger screen devices where this is happening.

What am I doing wrong where the images and coordinates on the screen don't just resize like they do on the Droid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite possible that those large devices (tablets) have much larger screens (width and height) than a typical phone.

Anyways, I'll share a function I wrote that will resize a bitmap to your desired width and height (so you can calculate this based off of the screen size, then have it re-scaled).  Of course, all this is doing is scaling it so make sure you have appropriate mdpi, hdpi versions.

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(Resources resources, String bitmapName, int width, int height)
    {   
        // this is just a Map of String, Bitmaps I use for cacheing
        Bitmap _bitmap = GraphicAssets.get(bitmapName); 
        if(_bitmap != null)
        {
            return _bitmap; // return cached result
        }
        else
        {   
            int fieldValue = 0;
            try
            {
                fieldValue = getFieldValue(bitmapName, R.drawable.class);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("getBitmap", "Cannot read field value", e);
            }
            Bitmap _bitmapPreScale = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, fieldValue);

            int oldWidth = _bitmapPreScale.getWidth();
            int oldHeight = _bitmapPreScale.getHeight();
            int newWidth = width;
            int newHeight = height;

            // calculate the scale 
            float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / oldWidth;
            float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / oldHeight;

            // createa matrix for the manipulation
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            // resize the bit map
            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

            // recreate the new Bitmap
            Bitmap _bitmapScaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(_bitmapPreScale, 0, 0,  oldWidth, oldHeight, matrix, true);
            return _bitmapScaled;
        }

public int getFieldValue(String name, Class obj) throws
     NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException,
     IllegalAccessException
     {
         Field field = obj.getDeclaredField(name);

         int value = field.getInt(obj);

         return value;
     }
```

So call it by:

```
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(GetResources(), "name_of_image_in_res/drawable_folder_without_file_extension", DesiredWidth, DesiredHeight);
```

Comment: Scaling the bitmap won't really fix the problem.

Comment: You're already scaling the bitmaps for mdpi and hdpi, right?  You'd need to scale it for tablets too, I'd suspect until they add something into the Android API.

Comment: No, I basically put the 320x480 image in the drawable folder.  Then, on most WVGA screens that are 800x480, like the Droid, the bitmaps auto-scale because of how I specify anyDensity=false.  But for some reason, instead of scaling on tablets, the images squeeze up into the upper left of the screen.

Comment: I ended up scaling bitmaps.  I wasn't able to do this exact solution, but I am now scaling bitmaps based on what happens when the surface size changes.